# Drag, Drop and move Image within web application ASP.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

My requirements are

---

1. Drag an image from a list and Drop it in to a new Div(ImgContainer).original image should be still in the image list.

---

2. Dropped image should be able to move within that Div(ImgContainer).

---

Help me to do this. This is what I have done. I used ASP.net and 1.9.2(Legacy, for jQuery1.6+

```js
<script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Item1").draggable({
                containment: "#ImgContainer",
                cursor: 'move',
                appendTo: "#ImgContainer",
                helper: "clone"
            });
        });

        $(function () {

            ImgContainer.droppable({
                accept: "#gallery > li",
                activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $("img").clone(ui.draggable.clone()).appendTo(this);
                }
            });

        });

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
                <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:400px; float:left !important">

                    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                        <img id="Item1" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/home-128.png" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br />

                <div id="ImgContainer" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default" style="width:600px; height:500px" ondrop="drop(event)">

                    <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-ImgContainer">ImgContainer</span></h4>

                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to solve my problem. Thank you all and here is the solution

```js
$(function () {
    $("#ImgContainer").droppable({
        accept: '.drag',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
            if (!$clone.is('.insideContainer')) {
                $(this).append($clone.addClass('insideContainer').draggable({
                    containment: '#ImgContainer'
                }));
            }
        }
    });
    $(".drag").draggable({
        helper: 'clone'
    });
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix" style="float:left; background-color:white; height:500px; width:250px !important">

            <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:250px; float:left !important">
                <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                    <img id="Item1" class="drag" src="http://50.198.27.57:8081/imagesDoc/IPD/1.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px !important;" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" />
                </li>            
            </ul>
</div>

<div id="ImgContainer" style="height:300px; width:300px; float:right; background-color:silver !important">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine except 5 things:

- draggble/droppable are jquery UI methods. include it too first.
- you are calling the droppable on a plain javascript item `ImgContainer`, you need to select it using jQuery first: `$("#ImgContainer")`
- you are calling the draggable in the images, not on the list item, but you accept only list items in your droppable. add a `> img` to the accept attribute.
- the `ondrop` attribute in your container overrides the jquery dropapble drop. get rid of it.
- the dropepd items need to be declared as draggable again, since they are clones of the original

```js
$(function () {
    $("#Item1").draggable({
        containment: "#ImgContainer",
        cursor: 'move',
        appendTo: "#ImgContainer",
        helper: "clone"
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#ImgContainer").droppable({
        accept: "#gallery > li > img, #ImgContainer > img",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.clone().appendTo(this).draggable({
                containment: "#ImgContainer",
                cursor: 'move',
                appendTo: "#ImgContainer"
            });;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
        <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix" style="width:400px; float:left !important">
            <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
                <img id="Item1" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pictype-free-vector-icons/16/home-128.png" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <div id="ImgContainer" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default" style="width:600px; height:500px">
             <h4 class="ui-widget-header"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-ImgContainer">ImgContainer</span></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank You very much. I will check the code and come back to you if there is any other problem.

Comment: yep it is working but when I click on the clone it duplicates the image. how can I get rid of this duplication ?

Comment: In the drop function, append all newly created clones a class "clone". And then instead of calling .clone() for every dropped item, first check if its a clone or not. If its not a clone, then clone it. If it is a clone, then dont clone just use append.